# What certificate format does /usr/local/share/ca-certificates accept?

Tags: debian, certificates

There are different methods of storing a certificate file? DER, PEM, PKCS: PKCS7 & PKCS12?

Are all of these formats accept as valid in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certificates are added to the CA certificate database using the `update-ca-certificates` command.  This is a shell script that scans the source certificate directories and adds any certificates found to the certificate bundle (`/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`) as well as creating a symlink in `/etc/ssl/certs` to the certificate.

The `ca-certificates.crt` file is a concatenation of certificates, each in PEM format.

The script doesn't convert any certificate formats, therefore it assumes that all certificates in the source folders are in PEM format with a `.crt` file extension.

Comment: This is correct. Nevertheless, it drives me nuts that a text formatted (PEM) file must be named as a binary formatted (DER/CRT) one, in order to get installed with `update-ca-certificates` command.

Comment: @Václav - I'm not sure `.crt` means anything.  A file extension is just some letters after a dot.  Linux doesn't really care whether its `.crt`, `.pem` or .`dog` or `.cat`. It is odd that the _scripts_ accepts only certificates which end in `.crt` though.

Comment: yes, that's correct. What I'm saying is that DER format had been in use since 1980s and certificates have been stored with `.crt` ending. This is why people on the Internet keep referring to CRT format as binary format, along with DER format. Like in this question: superuser.com/questions/1207739/… Or this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/13732826/convert-pem-to-crt-and-key
Textual format PEM has appeared in 1990s, that is why certificate files with `.pem` extension may be associated in people's minds with textual format only. But you're right, this confusion isn't legit

Comment: Still relevant in 2023 for Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

> There are different methods of storing a certificate file? DER, PEM,
>   PKCS: PKCS7 & PKCS12?

Yes, these are.

And,

> Are all of these formats accept as valid in
>   /usr/local/share/ca-certificates?

From man update-ca-certificates FILES section:

```
   /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
          Directory of local CA certificates (with .crt extension).
```

I think the answer is no, only PEM .crt format may be accepted as valid in there, use it to be sure.